# enum to std::string with Boost PP - Improving syntax

Tags: c++, boost, enums, boost-preprocessor

I've started playing around with Boost's PP lib with an aim to write some small tool to help convert enumerations to strings.

I've manged to get a solution where enums defined with a macro will also generate a complementary ToString function.

I've played with various syntax styles, but I was unable to get one particular arrangement to work.

This is what I have.

```
    namespace Examples
    {
        // This will define an enum class with an underlying uint8_t type
        ENUM_W_STR
        (fruit, uint8_t,
            (apple)
            (banana)
        );

        // Like above but with a different construction syntax
        ENUM_W_STR_2
        (fruit2, uint8_t,
            apple,
            banana
        );

        // This variant allows values to be assigned
        ENUM_W_STR_VAL
        (fruit3, uint8_t,
            (apple)      (1)
            (banana)     (2)
            (orange)     (3)
        );
    }
```

but, this is what I would like.

```
    ENUM_W_STR_2
    (fruit2, uint8_t,
        apple = 10,
        banana = 20
    );
```

I had issues with splitting the 'apple = 10' string
when generating the switch statement in ToString. i.e., I could construct
the enum but not the ToString function.

Can this be achieved? If not with Boost PP, then some other means?

Here is the source code (g++ 4.7.2, boost 1.50; clang 3.3  boost 1.57)

```
    #include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
    #include <iostream>

    namespace EnumUtils{

    #define ENUMUTLS_STR_SWITCH_CASE(r, data, elem)\
        case data::elem : return BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem);

    #define ENUMUTIL_EVEN(r, data,i, v)  BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_PP_MOD_D(r, i, 2),   ,v)
    #define ENUMUTIL_ODD( r, data,i, v)  BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_PP_MOD_D(r, i, 2),= v, )
    #define ENUMUTIL_ENUM_LINE(r, data, i, v)     ENUMUTIL_EVEN(r,data,i,v)    ENUMUTIL_ODD(r,data,i,v)    BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(BOOST_PP_MOD_D(r,i,2))

    #define ENUMUTLS_STR_SWITCH_CASE_VAL_BASE(r, data, i, v)  BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_PP_MOD_D(r, i, 2),,ENUMUTLS_STR_SWITCH_CASE(r, data, v))
    #define ENUMUTLS_STR_SWITCH_CASE_VAL(     r, data, i, v)  ENUMUTLS_STR_SWITCH_CASE_VAL_BASE(r,data,i,v) 


    #define ENUM_W_STR(name, type, seq)\
        enum class name : type {\
            BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(seq)\
        };\
        inline const char* ToString(name v)\
        {\
            switch (v)\
            {\
                BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(\
                        ENUMUTLS_STR_SWITCH_CASE,\
                        name,\
                        seq)\
                default: return "unknown " BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(name);\
            }\
        }

    #define ENUM_W_STR_2(name, type, args...)\
        enum class name : type {\
            BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(args))\
        };\
        inline const char* ToString(name v)\
        {\
            switch (v)\
            {\
                BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(\
                        ENUMUTLS_STR_SWITCH_CASE,\
                        name,\
                        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(args))\
                default: return "unknown " BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(name);\
            }\
        }


    #define ENUM_W_STR_VAL(name, type, seq)\
        enum class name : type {\
            BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(\
                    ENUMUTIL_ENUM_LINE,\
                    name,\
                    seq)\
        };\
        inline const char* ToString(name v)\
        {\
            switch (v)\
            {\
                BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(\
                        ENUMUTLS_STR_SWITCH_CASE_VAL,\
                        name,\
                        seq)\
                default: return "unknown " BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(name) ;\
            }\
        };
    }

    namespace Examples 
    {
      ENUM_W_STR 
      (fruit, uint8_t,
        (apple)
        (banana)
      );

      ENUM_W_STR_2
      (fruit2, uint8_t,
        apple,
        banana
      );

      ENUM_W_STR_VAL
      (fruit3, uint8_t,
        (apple)      (1)
        (banana)     (2)
        (orange)     (3)
     );
    }

    int main ()
    {
        std::cout << Examples::ToString(Examples::fruit::apple)   << std::endl;
        std::cout << Examples::ToString(Examples::fruit::banana)  << std::endl;
        std::cout << Examples::ToString(Examples::fruit2::apple)  << std::endl;
        std::cout << Examples::ToString(Examples::fruit2::banana) << std::endl;
        std::cout << Examples::ToString(Examples::fruit3::apple)  << std::endl;
        std::cout << Examples::ToString(Examples::fruit3::banana) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

output:

```
apple
banana
apple
banana
apple
banana
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of trimming is possible using C++11 `constexpr` functions and a macro. Here is an outline of the approach:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr const char    terminators[] = " \t\r\n=";

// Note that this count includes the null terminator, which is deliberate.
constexpr size_t        terminator_count = sizeof(terminators);

// Checks if a character is a terminator at compile time.
constexpr bool is_terminator(char c, size_t index = 0)
{
    return
        index >= terminator_count ? false :
        c == terminators[index] ? true :
        is_terminator(c, index + 1);
}

// Computes enum constant length at compile time.
constexpr size_t constant_length(const char *s, size_t index = 0)
{
    return is_terminator(s[index]) ? index : constant_length(s, index + 1);
}

// Evaluates to characters from "from" up to length of "from".
constexpr char select(const char *from, size_t from_length, size_t index)
{
    return index >= from_length ? '\0' : from[index];
}



constexpr const char    *foo = "apple = 10";
constexpr size_t        foo_length = constant_length(foo);

// You should use a macro to generate this, either from Boost, or your own.
// Ideally, the user would be able to change the maximum string length.
constexpr const char    trimmed[] =
    {select(foo, foo_length, 0), select(foo, foo_length, 1),
     select(foo, foo_length, 2), select(foo, foo_length, 3),
     select(foo, foo_length, 4), select(foo, foo_length, 5),
     select(foo, foo_length, 6), select(foo, foo_length, 7)};

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << trimmed << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
apple = 10
apple
```

There is a limitation on the maximum length of the constant name, as you can see from how `trimmed` is defined. As it says, the maximum length should probably be controlled by an optional macro that the user could define if they run into problems. Of course, the default should be more than the 8 you see in my sketch above :)

If you are interested, I have just released an enum library whose declaration syntax is nearly the same as what you described in your question (though the internals are quite different): http://aantron.github.io/better-enums

I will be adding this kind of compile-time string trimming to the library shortly to make its `to_string` method `constexpr` – it is currently the only thing that the library is forced to delay until runtime.

Comment: How do you extract the token from the macro invocation? i.e. how do you #define `MACRO(apple = 10)` to expand to `apple`?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, and the code above doesn't do that. What it does is create a static `char` array that contains `apple\0` using some `constexpr` functions, which is good enough for defining an enum with `constexpr` string conversions. Let me know if you would like me to explain or clarify how that works.

Comment: Nevermind, I now understand your approach. You simply use the whole expression in the enum declaration and "eat" the assignment (if any) when generating the values array. That's pretty clever.